# Error: Property 'isEmpty' cannot be accessed on 'String?' because it is potentially null. Try accessing using ?. instead

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to check `value` using `if` but the app crash on that line. I am using flutter.

```
 if (value == null || value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
          return 'Please enter a valid email.';
        }
```

getting that
Error: Property 'isEmpty' cannot be accessed on 'String?' because it is potentially null.
Try accessing using ?. instead.

Comment: That's because `value` can be `null`. Try `( value?.isEmpty ?? true )` so it returns true as if it is empty, in case it is null.

Comment: But I don't want to give some default value.

Comment: Then add another `if` before the current one. `if (value!=null)... if (value!.isEmpty)`

Comment: crash on that line.

Comment: My firt comment is the most optimal way IMO.

Comment: Strange. That code should run fine. It does for me. Because it is smart enough that to see it can't be null at `isEmpty`. Also with the error you describe you usually can't even run the code. But you talk about a crash. Is it really a crash or a compiler error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update Flutter and Dart to the latest versions. The error you describe should not happen.

This example is compiling and running perfectly fine, printing:

> Please enter a valid email.

> null

With no warnings or errors.

```
String? isValid(String? value) {
  if (value == null || value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
     return 'Please enter a valid email.';
  }
  
  return null;
}

void main() {
  print(isValid(null));
  print(isValid('valid@email.example.com'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

`value.isEmpty`

With

`(value.toString()).isEmpty`

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead

```
if((value != null && (value.isEmpty() || 
!value.contains('@'))) || (value == 
null)){

}
```

If you have declared a variable to be nullable and did not assign a default value, and later you want to use isEmpty on that variable, you must first check that the variable is not null before checking if it's empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my comment as answer so you can have better view of it:

```dart
 if (value == null || ( value?.isEmpty ?? true ) || (!value?.contains('@') ?? true )) {
          return 'Please enter a valid email.';
 }
```

Comment: You didn't check the value for "contains". ;)

Comment: Editted the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

YOU HAVE TO REPLACE SOME OF YOUR CODE

```
value.isEmpty
```

REPLACE IT WITH

```
( value?.isEmpty ?? true )
```